# I am trying to set a value to an array, but I can't seem to figure out why what I did on line 31 is wrong

Tags: c, arrays

I have a data file in the format <0:00> - <19321> , <1:00> - <19324>, up to <24:00> - <19648>, so for every hour there is the total power used so far(the total is incremented), I am supposed to calculate the power used, find the average, and the highest usage of power and its index(time), (I don't need help with finding the max power used at its time index). I traced the problem down to line 31, but I don't understand why what I did was wrong. Can someone explain to me why the code in line 31 isn't saving the value of power used into the array? And how I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
 float compute_usage(int num, int vals[], int use[], int *hi_idx)
 15 {
 16         int i;// i is a general counter for all for loops
 17         int r1, r2, u, v, pow_dif, temp;//for loop 1
 18         int tot;//for loop 2
 19         int max_use, init, fina, diff;//for loop 3 //don't have to worry about this for loop, I am good here
 20         float avg;//average power used
 21
 22         for(r1=r2=i=u=v=0;i<num;i++)//for loop 1
 23         {
 24                 r1= vals[v++];//I set values of every hour as reading 1 & 2(later)
 25 #ifdef DEBUG
 26                 printf("pre-debug: use is %d\n", use[u]);
 27 #endif
 28                 if(r1!=0 && r2!=0)
 29                 {
 30                         pow_dif = (r1 - r2);//I take the to readings, and calculate the difference, that difference is the power used in the interval between a time period 
 31                         use[u++] = pow_dif; //I'm suppose to save the power used in the interval in an array here
 32                 }
 33                 r2=r1;//the first reading becomes the second after the if statement, this way I always have 2 readings to calculate the power used int the interval
 34 #ifdef DEBUG
 35                 printf("for1-debug3: pow_dif is %d\n", pow_dif);
 36                 printf("for1-debug4: (%d,%d) \n", u, use[u]);
 37 #endif
 38
 39         }
 40         for(tot=i=u=0;i<num;i++)//for loop 2
 41         {tot = tot + use[u++];}
 42
 43         avg = tot/(num-1);
 44 #ifdef DEBUG
 45         printf("for2-debug1: the tot is %d\n", tot);
 46         printf("for2-debug2: avg power usage is %f\n", avg);
 47 #endif
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: "why the code in line 31 isn't saving the value of power used into the array". How are you coming to that conclusion? We can't help with such incomplete info and code. Please provide a [mcve] including exact input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I figured it out. After getting rid of extra variables that I didn't need, I discovered that I misplaced a counter, the u++ on line 31, and moved it outside of the use array, that way I set the value into the array first and then update the counter. That solved alot of my problems.

Comment: @PaulR , Thanks for the suggestion, but my professor is pretty adamant about learning how to debug code without using other tools first.

Answer (score 1):

Just to understand, how did you figure out that the code in line 31 is problematic? Is it the printf statement in line 36?

When you do this:

```
use[u++] = pow_dif; //I'm suppose to save the power used in the interval in an array here
printf("for1-debug4: (%d,%d) \n", u, use[u]);
```

The "u" variable in printf statement is incremented in the previous operation (u++), so you are looking past the element you changed.

```
use[u++] = pow_dif; //I.e. u=0 here, but u=1 after this is executed.
printf("...\n", u=1, use[1]);
```

What is the "i" for in this loop? Why don't you try "u++" in the for statement instead of "i++" and remove the "u++" in the use assignment expression?